# Ouvir/Gravar áudio do speechRecognition

Tags: ionic, ionic2

Eu construi uma aplicação simples usando o speechRecognition

```
startListening() {
  let options = {
    language: 'en-US'
  }
  this.speechRecognition.startListening().subscribe(matches => {
    this.matches = matches;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  });
  this.isRecording = true;
}
```

Eu gostaria de saber se posso utilizar um áudio gravado para realizar o speechRecognition ou se existe possibilidade de salvar o áudio que foi utilizado.